# ZF2 mocking authentification service

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have developed simple authentification using this tutorial http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/zend-framework-2-create-login-authentication-using-authenticationservice-with-rememberme/. Everything works fine, but now I have unit testing issues.

To check if user is authentified I am using:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $auth = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('AuthService');

    $e->getTarget()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
        ->attach('Admin', \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
                 function($e) use ($auth) {
            $currentRouteName = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
            $allowed = array(
                'admin/login',
                'admin/',
            );
            if (in_array($currentRouteName, $allowed)) {
                return;
            }
            if (!$auth->hasIdentity()) {
                $url = $e->getRouter()->assemble(array(),
                                                 array('name' => 'admin/login'));
                $response = $e->getResponse();
                $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
                $response->setStatusCode(302);
                $response->sendHeaders();
            }
        });
}
```

And my mock code:

```
    $authMock = $this->getMock('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');

    $authMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('hasIdentity')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
    $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
    $serviceManager->setService('AuthService', $authMock);
```

My issue is that mocks `hasIdentity` is not being called during unit test. What I have Did wrong.

Comment: How do you know that your hasIdentity() isn't being called?

Comment: make sure you get the ServiceManager return the mock in the test just after setting it as the service.

Comment: @TimFountain `$authMock->expects($this->once())` fails

Comment: @gontrollez Yes it does. I tried `$serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();  $serviceManager->get('AuthService')->hasIdentity();` after setting mock and `hasIdentity` was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in bootstrap. onBootstrap is being called before mocking. So `get('AuthService')` needs to be called in event handler. Here is working bootstrap example:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $e->getTarget()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()
        ->attach('Admin', \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
                 function($e) use ($sm) {
            $auth = $sm->get('AuthService');
            $currentRouteName = $e->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
            $allowed = array(
                'admin/login',
                'admin/',
            );
            if (in_array($currentRouteName, $allowed)) {
                return;
            }
            if (!$auth->hasIdentity()) {
                $url = $e->getRouter()->assemble(array(),
                                                 array('name' => 'admin/login'));
                $response = $e->getResponse();
                $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
                $response->setStatusCode(302);
                $response->sendHeaders();
            }
        });
}
```